# deploy in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

am trying to deploy my application on google app engine
but getting following error

```
Starting update of app: timezzzzpass, version: 4
Scanning files on local disk.
2011-06-06 17:46:22,095 ERROR appcfg.py:1965 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1914, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1627, in Begin
    self.Send('/api/appversion/create', payload=self.config.ToYAML())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1577, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 365, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 374, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 392, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 353, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 1109, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 367, in do_open
    raise url_error
URLError: <urlopen error (11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 76, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 72, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3592, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3583, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2229, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3368, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2630, in Update
    app_summary = self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2619, in UpdateVersion
    lambda path: open(os.path.join(basepath, path), 'rb'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1914, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1627, in Begin
    self.Send('/api/appversion/create', payload=self.config.ToYAML())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1577, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 365, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 374, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 392, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 353, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 1109, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 367, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error (11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
2011-06-06 17:46:22 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

how to resolve this stuff...thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a DNS lookup problem; are you able to connect to appengine.google.com with your browser? (see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=126 )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are behind an authenticated proxy which blocks you from deploying the application.

```
If you are running appcfg.py behind an HTTP proxy, you must tell appcfg.py the name of the proxy. To set an HTTP proxy for appcfg.py, set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables.

Using Windows (in Command Prompt):

set HTTP_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
appcfg.py update myapp
```

if you are running your application behind an authenticated proxy. You can try something like this

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://companyLogin:pwd@www-proxy.company.org.au:8080
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://companyLogin:pwd@www-proxy.company.org.au:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not behind a proxy, certain application settings might be causing this.

Set your port to something valid (like 8080) and make sure your Deployment Server is set to appengine.google.com